# if i want to play mp3's what is the difference between lame and MCI(VFW32)?

Tags: c++, mp3, lame, mci

basic question , i need to play mp3's in my application in windows 
when goggling i got allot of tutorials about VFW32.lib to play mp3's 
and i know lame , what is the best option for playing mp3's in c++?

Answer (score 0):

[VfW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_for_Windows) is an API that predates DirectShow on Windows, and was the original API that provided access to the system's video codecs. I'd wager that today, it's extremely non-portable, and shouldn't be used. Instead, prefer either the [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454(VS.85).aspx) API or a separate library like either Lame or [libmad](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/) or a framework like [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: does ffmpeg is free ( not gpl ? )